# export datagridview to txt with vb6.0

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, datagridview, vb6, export-to-text

I would like to ask how to export datagridview from vb6.0 to .txt format? I write this code to view the content of table to datagridview

`Call Buka
koneksi.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rsDTS.Open "select * from TBL_DTSHEET where KDKRY = '" & txtKdKry.Text & "' and (TGLWORK between '" & Format(dtAwal.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "' and '" & Format(dtAkhir.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "')", koneksi
With rsDTS
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
        mvBookmark = .Bookmark
    End If
End With
Set DataGrid1.DataSource = rsDTS.DataSource`

And now I wonder how can I export this datagridview into a file with format .txt?
anyone can help?
thanks

Comment: `DataGridView` is a .Net widget.  You probably mean something else, but if you are fiddling with an explicit Recordset anyway it hardly factors into any of this.  This is what is known as a "red herring."

Answer (score 0):

I think I can solved my own problem by adding some code like this

```
Open "D:\textfile.txt" For Output As #1
Do While rsDTS.EOF = False
    Print #1, rsDTS.Fields("KDDTS").Value & ", " & rsDTS.Fields("KDHDTS").Value & ", " & rsDTS.Fields("TGLWORK").Value
    rsDTS.MoveNext
Loop
Close #1
```

Hope this can help others

Comment: `Do Until rsDTS.EOF` would be cleaner and easier to read.  You might want to read up on how Boolean expressions work.